# Does inverse limit commute with stalk?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Suppose $\mathcal F_n$ is an inverse system of sheaves over a topological space $X$, and let $\mathcal F$ be their inverse limit. Then for any $x\in X$, do we have $\mathcal F_x=\varprojlim \mathcal F_{n,x}$? I think it is not true.. But could you provide a counterexample(or just prove it)?

Comment: This is answered in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80321/is-the-stalk-of-the-colimit-of-sheaves-equal-to-the-colimit-of-the-stalks.

Comment: @QiZhu Ah thanks!